Правильный порядок членов класса друг относительно друга
В каком порядке в классе следует размещать поля, свойства, конструкторы и прочее? Пробовал найти ответ здесь и на Learn.Microsoft, но не нашел, поэтому обратился к чату GPT, который предложил следующий порядок:
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

/// <summary>
/// Класс ExampleClass демонстрирует порядок расположения всех членов, включая поля, константы, инициализаторы,
/// свойства, события, методы, реализации интерфейсов, вложенные классы и деструктор.
/// </summary>
public class ExampleClass
{
    // Вложенные классы
    public class NestedClass
    {
        // Код вложенного класса
    }

    // Константы и статические поля
    public const int PublicConstValue = 10; // Публичная константа
    private const int PrivateConstValue = 5; // Приватная константа
    private static readonly int StaticReadonlyField = 15; // Статическое поле readonly
    private static int StaticPrivateField; // Приватное статическое поле

    // Поля
    public readonly int ReadOnlyField; // Поле только для чтения
    private int privateField; // Приватное поле
    public int PublicField; // Публичное поле

    // Статический инициализатор
    static ExampleClass()
    {
        StaticPrivateField = 20; // Инициализация статического поля
    }

    // Инициализаторы экземпляра
    public ExampleClass()
    {
        ReadOnlyField = 25; // Инициализация поля readonly в конструкторе
        privateField = 30; // Инициализация приватного поля
    }

    // Свойства
    public static int PublicStaticProperty { get; set; } // Публичное статическое свойство
    protected static int ProtectedStaticProperty { get; private set; } // Защищенное статическое свойство
    private static int PrivateStaticProperty { get; set; } // Приватное статическое свойство

    public int PublicProperty { get; set; } // Публичное свойство
    protected int ProtectedProperty { get; set; } // Защищенное свойство
    private int PrivateProperty { get; set; } // Приватное свойство

    // События
    public static event EventHandler PublicStaticEvent; // Публичное статическое событие
    private static event EventHandler PrivateStaticEvent; // Приватное статическое событие

    public event EventHandler PublicEvent; // Публичное событие
    private event EventHandler PrivateEvent; // Приватное событие

    // Методы
    public static void PublicStaticMethod()
    {
        // Код публичного статического метода
    }

    protected static void ProtectedStaticMethod()
    {
        // Код защищенного статического метода
    }

    private static void PrivateStaticMethod()
    {
        // Код приватного статического метода
    }

    public void PublicMethod()
    {
        // Код публичного метода
    }

    protected void ProtectedMethod()
    {
        // Код защищенного метода
    }

    private void PrivateMethod()
    {
        // Код приватного метода
    }

    // Импорт методов WinAPI
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, int bShow);

    // Реализация интерфейса
    public interface IExampleInterface
    {
        void InterfaceMethod();
    }

    // Явная реализация интерфейса
    void IExampleInterface.InterfaceMethod()
    {
        // Код интерфейсного метода
    }

    // Деструктор (для очистки ресурсов)
    ~ExampleClass()
    {
        // Код деструктора для освобождения ресурсов
    }
}

Прошу знающих людей высказаться по поводу предложенного порядка - он корректен, или есть ошибки?

Книга Framework Design Guidelines, третье издание.
Приложение A.4 FILE ORGANIZATION.
DO group members into the following sections in the specified order:
All const fields
All static fields
All instance fields
All auto-implemented static properties
All auto-implemented instance properties
All constructors
Remaining members
All nested types
CONSIDER grouping the remaining members into the following sections in the specified order:
Public and protected properties
Methods
Events
All explicit interface implementations
Internal members
Private members

Благодарю за ответ! То есть получается, что события идут после методов. А где следует размещать методы, вызывающие эти события? А что подразумевается под "Private members"? Приватные члены, не перечисленные в других подгруппах, или вообще все - включая поля, методы, свойства и т.п.? Тот же вопрос и про "Internal members"...

Было бы неплохо завернуть английский в цитатку и добавить перевод.

Для студии есть расширения, по выбору пункта в меню реорганизующие Ваш код - переставляют местами обозначенные регионы, переносят в выбранной последовательности поля, свойства, методы и прочее. Можно даже сортировать, к примеру, поля по типу данных или по имени, добавлять форматирование кода

@AlexanderSt Спасибо за ответ! Реорганизуют они, если я правильно понял, в порядке, который определил пользователь? Если так, то узнать из них правильный порядок не получится... Но все равно было бы здорово, если бы Вы подсказали или конкретное расширение, или хотя бы категорию, т.к. пока не совсем понятно даже как их искать.

@JamesBond - см. StyleCop Analyzers (он указывает, что неправильно, но сам не фиксит порядок) и CodeMaid

@JamesBond в моем случае я говорил про CodeMaid VS2022, но их там есть несколько с различным функционалом - XAML причёсывать, например

@AlexanderSt спасибо! Вообще, конечно, расширения расширениями, но они больше нужны для упрощения уже практической работы. Я же только учусь, поэтому просто хотел узнать правильны порядок членов класса, дабы код не превращался в кашу, в которой методы могут быть выше полей, например)
